# What is the most casual way to ask ''What do you reckon ?'' in Japanese?

Tags: colloquial-language, phrases

I want to know a colloquial way to ask: What do you reckon/think ?

For example:

I just cooked a meal and I turn to my Japanese friend and say: What do you reckon ? (I'm seeking approval whilst smiling proudly at my masterpiece)

I click on a movie on Netflix and turn to my Japanese friend and say ? What do you reckon ? (I want to know whether they want to watch this movie or not)

I dress up nice and smart for an event and after fixing my tie turn to my Japanese friend and say: What do you reckon ? (I'm seeking approval or advice on how I look)

Would ''dou desu ka ?'' be appropriate ?
Also what would be the most colloquial way to answer?
Yeah, it's fine. Meh, it'll do. etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most casual way is a simple 「[どう?]{HLH}」 (even omitting the ですか).

How they answer kind of depends on the context, and (probably more so) how close of a relationship you have.  For agreement they could use something like 「うん」, 「いい」, 「いける」, 「オッケー」, 「おいしそう」 (for the food), 「似合う」 (for the outfit), 「面白そう」 for the movie, etc.  For disagreement, things like 「あんまり」, 「全然」, 「だめ」, 「気持ち悪い」, 「ちょっと…」, 「まあ」, and so on.

As you (probably) know, Japanese are very indirect and non-confrontational.  So someone is more likely to answer 「ちょっと」 in order to not offend you instead of 「だめ」.  Unless it's someone *very* close to you like your best friends or a sibling.

Comment: I think that even if you extend どう slightly to pronounce it with rising intonation at the end, the pitch accent is still [どう]{HL}.

Comment: I'd also be wary grouping plain "いい" (vs. いいよ or いいと思う(よ)) into the agreement category. It often if not always comes across as "I'm fine (without it, etc.)".

Comment: Is マー meant to be まあ? (If so, it's quite unlikely to be spelled like that.)